# File type validation!! for generated input file tag elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, validation

```
JSP:
----

<div ID="items">  
input id="file5" type="file" path="files" name="files" size="40" /> Other documents  
</div> 

Javascript:
-----------
<script type="text/javascript">  
             var items=1;  
            function AddItem() {  
                var div=document.getElementById("items");  
                var button=document.getElementById("add");  
                items++;  
                newitem="";  
                newitem+="<input type=\"file\" path=\"files\" name=\"files\"";// + items;  
                newitem+="\"id=file"+items;  
                newitem+="\" size=\"40\"> Other documents";  
                newitem+=" <input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" id=\"delButton"+items;  
                newitem+="\" value=\"\" name=\"button"+items;  
                newitem+="\" onclick=deletethisRow("+items+")>";  
                newnode=document.createElement("div");  
                newnode.setAttribute("id","child"+items);  
                newnode.innerHTML=newitem;  
                div.insertBefore(newnode,button);  
            }  
            function deletethisRow(obj){  
                var fileElement=document.getElementById("file"+obj);  
                var buttonElement=document.getElementById("delButton"+obj);  
                var childDivName="child"+obj;  
                if (buttonElement) {      
                    var child = document.getElementById(childDivName);  
                    var parent = document.getElementById("items");  
                    parent.removeChild(child);   
                }  
             }   
</script>  

---
```

Above is the JSP code as well as JavaScript snippets.. I'm trying to validate the input files....

I want to allow only jpg,png,pdf,doc,docx file types to be upload??
Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks and regards,
Satish Krishnamurthy

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input tag:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept=".someext, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

But please don't rely on client-side validation. Check it server-side or people can disable the client-side checks and upload even executable scripts.

Comment: accept attribute will not work no some browsers.. I've tried in FF (latest version) It didn't work for me

Comment: You're right. It seems like they removed the feature in the newer versions... Does not change the fact that you should check it on the server.

Comment: Agreed! I'm new to javascript.. can you tell me how to implement server-side validation?

Comment: There are a lot of sites on google. Check e.g. http://www.ultsec.com/php-secure-file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function Checkfilesextension()
{
    var fileToupload = document.getElementById('elementId');
    var fileName = fileToupload .value;
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    ext.toLowerCase

if(ext =="GIF" || other extension) // add other extensions
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    alert("Upload only the allowed files");
    return false;
}
}
```

This would check for the extension of the files....have not tested the code though

Comment: I tried this but I'm generating id dynamically through javascript. Hence, If my Javascript can't find the value for the  for say input file tag id no. 7 i.e id="file7" which is not been created then the whole code fails.... 

and I noticed when I was debugging in firefox.. Upon hovering on the 'input file' field it didn't display the id#. It just displayed "input" whereas it should have displayed "input#file3" or "input#file4" etc...

Comment: if an element is not been created then document.getElementById('elementNotCreated') would return null. you can check for not null and then the execute the rest of the script. you can also have a global variable, and add the file names when u create and use this variable in the validation function.

Comment: Nope.. 
document.getElementById('elementNotCreated') will fail the whole script. It doesnt get executed..